# UISearchController with nil searchResultsController

Tags: swift, ios9, uisearchcontroller

I am using UISearchController with UITableView, and using same table view on my base view controller to display the search results (doing with not specifying a seperate search results controller as `searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)` ).

However, despite setting searchResultsController as nil, an empty transparent `_UISearchControllerView` is still being presenting on top of my view controller when search is active.

Is there a way to prevent this and keep my view controller on the top of the view controller hiearchy on search?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm experiencing the exact same issue, and have no idea what to do.

Comment: @Jeffrey No, I couldn't find a solution at that times.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove that by setting the `dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation` property of search controller to false

```
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
```

Comment: It's just a visual property as i know, doesn't work as I want to. Did you try it and see in view debugger, maybe i am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

By default, `UISearchController` will dim the view it is presented over. This is useful if you are using another view controller for `searchResultsController`. In your code, you have set the current view to show the results, so you do not want to dim your view.

```
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
```

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 13, `UISearchController#dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation` is deprecated.

The correct way to prevent the containing view controller from being obscured is to use `obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation` instead:

```
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
```

See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchcontroller/1618656-obscuresbackgroundduringpresenta):

> When the value of this property is `true`, the search controller obscures the view controller containing your searchable content as soon as the user interacts with the search bar. When this property is `false`, the search controller does not obscure the original view controller. This property controls only whether the original view controller is initially obscured. When the user enters text in the search bar, the search controller immediately displays the search results controller with the results.
>
> **If you use the same view controller to display the searchable content and search results, it is recommended that you set this property to `false`**. The default value of this property is `true`.

Answer (score -1):

Hello folk please try this.

```
-(void) searchBar: (UISearchBar *) searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)     searchText{
NSMutableArray *sortedData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if ([searchText isEqualToString:@""]) {
        _localArray = _mainArray; // you must take a local array
    }
    else{
       //show your sorted data
    }

}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
searchBar.text = nil;
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
[self.view endEditing:YES];
}
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
[searchBar resignFirstResponder];
[self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```